# Current date won't insert; I keep getting error – PHP MySQL

Tags: php, date, insert, bind

I'm trying to register a date for every time the form is submitted but I don't know — I just can't seem to figure it out. I looked at many other posts, but can't seem to find the answer.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO coffee (
        name,
        ddown-num,
        txtDate,
        radio-ad,
        ddown-yn,
        sub-date
    ) VALUES (
        :name,
        :ddown-num,
        :txtDate,
        :radio-ad,
        :ddown-yn,
        now()
    )
";

$query_params = array(
    ':name' => $_POST['name'],
    ':ddown-num' => $_POST['ddown'],
    ':txtDate' => $_POST['txtDate'],
    ':radio-ad' => $_POST['agdis'],
    ':ddown-yn' => $_POST['yn']
);
```

I tried the "now()" method with single quotes and I also tried the last ":sub-date" instead of "now()" with ":sub-date => now()" too, and with ":sub-date => $current-date". $current-date = now(); .. but no difference.

and I tried this:

```
try
{
    // Execute the query to create the user
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ddown-num', $_POST['ddown']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':txtDate', $_POST['txtDate']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':radio-ad', $_POST['agdis']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ddown-yn', $_POST['yn']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sub-date', date("Y-m-d"));

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your entire CURRENT code block?

Comment: When you tried making `now()` a parameter did you remember to change `now()` in the query to `:sub-date`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you can use hyphens as a named placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html):

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
> - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

You are using `-` minus signs for both your parameters and your column names. You should quote these using backticks for the column names and I would get rid of them in the parameters:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO coffee (
        name,
        `ddown-num`,
        `txtDate`,
        `radio-ad`,
        `ddown-yn`,
        `sub-date`
    ) VALUES (
        :name,
        :ddownNum,
        :txtDate,
        :radioAd,
        :ddownYn,
        now()
    )
";
```

Comment: Nice it worked! Thank you. 
another question, if i changed my table and columns to utf-8, would i still need to add the backticks and remove the dashes?..i mean i did try it, without success. is there a way?

Comment: @user2448409 Yes, it is not related to character encoding but to the fact that mysql will assume the `-` to be a mathematical operator: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-functions.html

Comment: oh ya lol, thank you for reminding me :) and i appreciate everyone's help :)